# Define new category for custom modules Odoo 10

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo

I am developing a new module, and I would like to define a new module category named 'Foo' for this module, so in the manifest I can use:

```
'category': 'Foo'
```

What should be done to create this new category?

I want to later refer to it in the security definition as:

```
<field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_foo"/>
```

Odoo 10.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but I think you should create a new XML file with the following content:

```
<record id="module_category_foo" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">Foo</field>
    <field name="description">Foo description.</field>
    <field name="sequence">16</field>
    <field name="visible">True</field>
</record>
```

Then, you must call this XML file in the `data` parameter of the `__manifest__.py`.

But in the security definition, you must refer to it this way:

```
<field name="category_id" ref="your_current_module.module_category_foo"/>
```

As you have not declared the category inside `base` module.

But, I do not know if the `__manifest__.py` is going to recognize the category *Foo* (may be because it has not loaded the `data` files yet -where the declaration of the category is-), so, in this case, I guess you must create a new module (e.g. *foo_generation*), whose purpose is only create the category *Foo*, an then, add this module to the dependencies of the `__manifest__.py` of your other module. In this case, in the security definition, you must refer to it this way:

```
<field name="category_id" ref="foo_generation.module_category_foo"/>
```